# Angular is storing data from JSON response keeping double quotes (%22)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing, cookies

I have a PHP script returning this:

```
{"result": "0", "token":"atoken" }
```

the script is called with Angular:

```
$http.post( API["R001"], $scope.user, {}).then($scope.postSuccess, null);
```

and on success I process the response with this:

```
 $scope.postSuccess = function(response) {

    if(response.data.result == "0") {
        console.log(response.data.token);
        $cookies.putObject("token", response.data.token, {'path':'/'} );
        return;
    } ...
```

Now the problem is that the cookie is stored with this value:

```
%22atoken%22
```

that is keeping the double quotes.

Console.log() returns the value without quotes.

Comment: So where does the value `%22tokdvsd%22` come from? The JSON returns `atoken`.

Comment: Please break it down more and `console.log` the value at various stages. Figure out at what point `%22` gets introduced.

Comment: add `console.log(response.data.token);` just before the `$cookies.putObject(...)` line and see what you get.

Comment: Console log gives me the token without double quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried instead of using `$cookie.putObject` use `$cookie.put`

It seems to me you're trying to store a `string` into $cookie but
`putObject` accepts an object of type `Object` maybe it performs some parsing that causes the double quotes whilst `put` expects a string. Here's the [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#put)